# What SQL query should I perform to get the result set as I expected?

Tags: sql, postgresql

I'm having problem to get the result I need :/  these are my tablets. On Postgresql

```
       table: logins                              table: users
+------------------------+                 +------------------+
|   iduser  | date       |                 | iduser | name    |
|------------------------|                 |------------------|
|     1     |'2017-06-06'|                 |   1    | Joe     |
|------------------------|                 |------------------|
|     1     |'2017-06-06'|                 |   2    | Jane    |       
|------------------------|                 |------------------|
|     2     |'2017-06-07'|                 |   3    | Mary    |
|------------------------|                 +------------------+
|     3     |'2017-06-07'|
|------------------------|
|     3     |'2017-06-07'|
|------------------------|
|     3     |'2017-06-07'|
+------------------------+
```

Im Using this query:

```
SELECT name, date, count(*) FROM logins l
LEFT JOIN users u
ON u.iduser= l.iduser
GROUP BY 
u.name,l.date
ORDER BY 
l.date
```

This it what I got:

```
+-----------------------------------+
|  name    |    date      |   count |
|-----------------------------------|
| Joe      | '2017-06-06' |    2    |
|-----------------------------------|
| Jane     | '2017-06-07' |    1    |
|-----------------------------------|
| Mary     | '2017-06-07' |    3    |
+-----------------------------------+
```

but what I really need to get from the result its this:

```
+-----------------------------------+
|  name    |    date      |   count |
|-----------------------------------|
| Joe      | '2017-06-06' |    2    |
|-----------------------------------|
| Jane     | '2017-06-06' |    0    |
|-----------------------------------|
| Mary     | '2017-06-06' |    0    |
|-----------------------------------|
| Joe      | '2017-06-07' |    0    |
|-----------------------------------|
| Jane     | '2017-06-07' |    1    |
|-----------------------------------|
| Mary     | '2017-06-07' |    3    |
+-----------------------------------+
```

What should I do? please help!!! thanks a lot! ^^

Comment: please tag the DBMS you are using

Comment: I'm Using Postgresql

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In SQL Server & Postgres:

Getting all combinations of `date` and `users`, then `left join` to `login`:

```
select 
    d.date
  , u.name
  , count(l.iduser) as login_count
from (select distinct date from logins) d
  cross join users u 
  left join logins l 
    on l.iduser=u.iduser 
   and l.date=d.date
group by d.date, u.name
```

rextester demo (sql server): http://rextester.com/THJE85313

rextester demo (postgres): http://rextester.com/BNHE97192

returns:

```
+---------------------+------+-------------+
|        date         | name | login_count |
+---------------------+------+-------------+
| 2017-06-06 00:00:00 | Jane |           0 |
| 2017-06-07 00:00:00 | Jane |           1 |
| 2017-06-06 00:00:00 | Joe  |           2 |
| 2017-06-07 00:00:00 | Joe  |           0 |
| 2017-06-06 00:00:00 | Mary |           0 |
| 2017-06-07 00:00:00 | Mary |           3 |
+---------------------+------+-------------+
```